# How can I post params to be used as an object in Django

Tags: python, django, frontend

I want to send an ajax Post request to my server with a param to be used like an object:

```
student_name = request.data.get('student_info', {}).get('name')
```

When I send the params like this:

***student_info: {"name":"Tom", "age": 20}***

It produce the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'
```

The best answer is what I don't need to change my back-end,
and solve my problem by sending data properly.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

The request.data is just a string when posted from the front-end.

You could just do,

```
student_name = request.data.get('student_info', {})['name']
```

You could also do,

```
import json
student_name = json.loads(request.data.get('student_info')).get('name')
```

But, this may raise error if there is no student_info in request.data

Previous answer was a mistake from my side. Apologies from my behalf for that.

Comment: please, let me know if there is any mistake I've said or posted... Anonymous down votes are just cowardice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send Json content and not key string values :

```
data: JSON.stringify({"student_info":"{'name':'Tom', 'age': 20}'})
```

your error is `request.data.get('student_info', {})` return a string so you cannot retrieve the `name` with `get('name')`

And `json.loads(request.data.get('student_info', {}))` in Django part :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope you did stringify your data at the front-end. I once solved this problem by sending data from ajax as follows:

```
var js = {"name":"nguyen","age":"1"};
$.post("/", {'data': JSON.stringify(js)}, function(ret){
        console.log(ret)
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should send a JSON Object from your client. Set

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

in your request header and write your Object in the request body like so:

```
{"student_info":{"name":"Tom", "age": 20}}
```

Then you will directly get an object.

As easy as that :)